# Tablesorter and automatic sorter digit?

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I have a lot of table using tablesorter on my website and I'm looking for a way to sort "sorter: 'digit' a column that have a specific classname : "class="note".

I know of to do this with a header :

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({ 
headers: {
     0: { sorter: 'digit' } // column number, type
 }  });
```

But is there a generic way to do that is the html like this :

`<th class="{sorter: 'digit'}">Note</th>`

or with the classname `<th class="note">Note</th>` somewhere in the javascript like this

```
$(".tablesorter .note").tablesorter() ...
```

?

Because my column "note" is sometime the third column, sometime the fifth etc.

I ask this because without the "digit" order specified, tablesorter does not know how to sort numbers ... Here is un jsfiddle to show what I mean : http://jsfiddle.net/2cmuy39L/

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you can accomplish this at least two different ways:

1. Add a `sorter-digit` class name to the headers

   ```
   <th class="note sorter-digit">Note</th>
   ```
2. use a Class name in the [`headers` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#headers) (added in v2.17.0) - [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4255/):

   ```
   headers : {
     '.note' : { sorter: 'digit' }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you ! it wasn't working for me because I was using tablesorter from this website http://tablesorter.com/docs/ and you use from this website http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/ but yours is the last version and note mine. But it's a lot heavier ^^ mine 17ko, yours 31ko ^^